# HAProxy multiple certificates error on first call

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a load balancer running HAProxy 1.7.5-2 with the following setup:

- multiple https-enabled frontends
- each frontend binds the following (for different IPs): `bind <ip>:443 ssl crt /opt/certbot/haproxy/fullchains/__fallback.pem crt /opt/certbot/haproxy/fullchains`

Note, that I use let's encrypt certificates and have multiple websites under the same frontend. The above selects automatically the right certificate for the requested hostname. Now I am currently experiencing the following issue: Whenever I open up a site (note, that all have HSTS enabled) inside an incognito window, I get the fallback certificate and only after reloading the site, the website itself loads with the correct certificate. Anyone got an idea, where this issue might come from?